# SSRS in SQL Server 2008 R2 Sorting By Percentages(Expression)

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, report

I'm building a report that has a top 10 table. I'm trying to sort the values by the percentage of that value. But the sorting(Z-A) (DESC) is carried out as 90-80-70-100. So the 100 percentile is presented at the back of the bunch. 
Does anyone know why that keeps happening.

Sorting is based on the expression:

```
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FORMAT(System.Math.ROUND(Sum(Fields!Servicelevel.Value), 0) / System.Math.ROUND(Sum(Fields!Beantwoord.Value), 0), "P")
```

Results:

```
    Nr.   % 
    1   95.17 %
    2   92.93 %
    3   92.56 %
    4   87.70 %
    5   87.23 %
    6   86.43 %
    7   82.38 %
    8   82.20 %
    9   81.29 %
    10  100.00 %
```

So Nr. 10 should be on the first spot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Values are sorted in alphabetical order, they are strings. Use numeric types to store percentage values.

Comment: Remove the `format` and `round` from the expression and sort on just the calculation since that is really what you want to sort on.

Comment: That is correct and works great! Thank you R.Richards